# Should I start the RunWorkerAsync method of a BackgroundWorker subclass within the constructor?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a subclass of Background worker. After I register all the arguments in the New block, I want to kick off the RunWorkerAsync method. Is this going to give me trouble later and/or is this bad practice?

```
        Public Sub New(ByVal theNum As Integer)
            _theNum = theNum
            Me.RunWorkerAsync()  ' automatically start running; will this bite me?
        End Sub
```

In the case of this subclass, as soon as the worker is instantiated, I know that I want work to kick off immediately.

Comment: In this case, it works just fine. But I'm new to BackgroundWorker, and I'm wondering if there's any reason to avoid having self-starting workers.

Comment: I don't particularly see a problem here - I'll let others chime in if needed.

Comment: If your class raises EVENTS then it is possible that you might miss them since the work will already have started (and possibly raised an event) before you've had a chance to subscribe to events of that instance of the class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a design standpoint, I would recommend keeping the constructor as free from doing any actual work as is possible.  The reason for that is because work in the constructor can lead to unexpected behavior and general buggy-ness.  It can also make your code less flexible and much harder to unit-test.  But those suggestions apply to all work done in the constructor.  They don't apply specifically to just background workers.  And just like any maxim, there are sometimes exceptions-to-the-rule.

From a technical stand point, as long as you are calling it after the designer-inserted `InitializeComponent` method is called, then you should not have any negative ramifications.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the kind of insight I need, especially the hint toward InitializeComponent, which I wasn't even thinking about yet.